# Why a if(somestring) is true Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why output of this code is 18. I am not able to understand why first if condition is true. It will be helpful if someone can explain it to me.

```
var x = 5;
var y = 1;

if(!!"false"){
    x = x + 10; 
    y = 3;
};
if(!!false) {
    x = x + 10; 
    y = y + 8;
};
alert(x+y)
```

Thanks

Comment: Because this is how JavaScript is defined. In this case it is how `!` works: any (and only) "false-y" values will be true when negated. The difference observed is that `"false"` is *not* a "false-y" value, because it is a non-empty string and thus `!"false"` is false.

Comment: If Boolean operator get applied on a non empty string it always evaluate to true e.g. console.debug(Boolean("false")) returns true. As you are using logical not operator the expression get converted into boolean value  behind the scene and then two not operators flip flop the value to false and back to true.

Answer (score 3):

It is because the **string** `"false"` evaluates to true when converted to `boolean`. Even though it **stores the text** `false` it has **no relation** to the `false` value.
Hence it evaluates to `true`, which is negated twice and we get `true` as the result.

There is only a few **"falsy" values** in JavaScript - values that evaluate to false. You can read about those [for example here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).

- `false`
- 0 (zero)
- `""`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

The linked website shows an example very similar to yours:

```
var a = !!(0); // variable is set to false
var b = !!("0"); // true
```

The sole reason for the result is the fact, that **0** is **falsy**, but **"0"** **is not**.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Your answer is very helpful for me.

Comment: @MohitDagar then please consider accepting this as correct to close the question

Answer (score 1):

The first `if` statement would execute always since `!!"false"` true because a non-empty string is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in Javascript and `!!(truthy value)` would be always true. The second if statement would always fail because `false` is a boolean value(which is [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)) so the output of `!!(falsy value)` is false.

Since the first if statement is executing value of `x` would increment to `15`, `y` would be `3` and finally, result would be `18` ( `15 + 3` ).

Answer (score 1):

`!!"false"` is boolean `true` ,So it will go inside the first `if` condition.

Inside the condition , the new value of `x` will `15` and new value of `y` will be 3, which sums up to 18.

In second `if` the condition `!!false` is set to `false` so it wont go inside the loop
So finally the value is `18` which you are seeing in alert